# category of sheaves of abelian groups properties

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am working on some properties of categories. And I would like to know how could we characterize the category of sheaves of abelian groups on a point? It seems to be equivalent to the category of abelian groups but I do not know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's even isomorphic to the category of abelian groups. The functor sends a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ to its group of global sections $\Gamma(\mathcal{F})$. The inverse functor is that given an abelian group, you can build a sheaf on the one point space by assigning its sections on the point to be the abelian group (and its sections on the empty set to be 0).

(And given a morphism of sheaves, we get a morphism of the groups of global sections, and conversely.)

EDIT in response to comment: to build a presheaf of abelian groups on a topological space, you have to assign an abelian group $\mathcal{F}$ to each open subset $U$, and restriction maps $\mathcal{F}(V) \to \mathcal{F}(U)$ whenever $U \subseteq V$. The one-point space has only two open subsets. Moreover, for the presheaf to be a sheaf, we'll need $\mathcal{F}(\emptyset) = 0$ and the restriction map $\mathcal{F}(\{\text{pt}\}) \to 0$ has to be the zero map. So the only piece of data we actually get to pick is the abelian group $\mathcal{F}(\{\text{pt}\})$

Comment: Hi, I don't understand well how I could build this sheaf. Could you give more explanation. @hunter

Comment: @algebra1112 i edited the answer above.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, and when you say The one-point space has only two open subsets you mean the whole space and the empty set? And when you say that the functor sends a sheaf to its group of global section you mean $F(X)$ which is an abelian group? We shouldn't send instead a point sheaf on a point (stalk) to its group of global sections. It's the first time I am reading this theory, that's why I am asking a lot. Thanks. @hunter